# Automating Deleting Files Not Working Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, fileshare

We deal with over a thousand files. I want to use Powershell to automate removing files older than a year for each folder path after checking to see if it exists in the archive location. It it does, it removes from backup. It if does not, it moves the file from backup to archive locations. I am not sure what is wrong with my code. It does not give me an error message that I can go off on. When I find the value for each variable, everything looks fine to me. What is happening is that the files are not being moved over.

```
Function Delete-Files ($src)
    {
        #finding date to remove i.e, if today's date is 5/19/2021, then the code would only be looking at files that are before 5/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
        $date2remove = (Get-Date).Date.AddYears(-1)
        $clientLocation = "\\fileshare\test\test\test\Backup\Client\"
        #getting Client folder #
        $clients = (Get-ChildItem $clientLocation -Directory).name
        foreach ($client in $clients)
        {
            $srcparent = $clientLocation + $client + $src -join "\"
            #ignoring the paths that do not contain $src
            if (Test-Path $srcparent)
            {
            #getting files that are older than a year
            $files2remove = Get-ChildItem $srcparent | Where-Object {( $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date2remove)}
                foreach ($file2remove in $files2remove)
                {
                    #getting the year for the last write time for each file
                    $year2remove = $file2remove.LastWriteTime.Year
                    $archive = '\\fileshare\test\test\test\archive\' + $year2remove + '\Client\' + $client + $src -join '\'
                    #if archive folder doesn't exist, create
                    if (!(Test-Path $archive))
                    {
                        New-Item -Path $archive
                    }
                    #getting the name of each file that needs to be removed
                    $fileName2remove = $file2remove.name
                    $archiveFile = $archive + $fileName2remove -join '\'
                    $srcFile = $srcparent + $fileName2remove -join '\'
                    #if file exists in archive, remove
                    if (Test-Path $archiveFile)
                    {
                        Remove-Item -Path $srcFile
                        "$srcFile"
                    }
                    #if file does not exist, move file from backup to archive
                    else
                    {
                        Move-Item -Path $srcFile -Destination $archive
                        "$archiveFile"
                    }
                }
            }
            }
    }
    
    $src = "\folder1\"
    Delete-Files $src
    
    $src = "\folder1\folder2\"
    Delete-Files $src
    
    $src = "\folder3\"
    Delete-Files $src
```

Comment: In all these places where you are using `-join '\'` you are already concatenating the strings together using + so the -join is not doing anything  or what it does might be unexpected.  It would be better to use `Join-Path` instead.  e.g. `$archive + $fileName2remove -join '\'` change to `Join-Path $archive $fileName2remove`, `$srcparent = $clientLocation + $client + $src -join '\'` to `$srcparent = Join-Path $clientLocation (Join-Path $client $src )`

Comment: I have added this.  It still doesn't work, but I did not know you could do this so thank you for the help.

Comment: Run your code with debugging turned on and step through the output.  This will elucidate where the problem is.  Paste the relevant output from debug so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: Figured out the issue.  I needed to declare that the new-item is a directory. Thank you for everyone's help!